# Display Image from Mysql Database is slow how would i increase the load speed? asynchronous

Tags: asp.net, mysql

Hello I'm doing a school project i have a page with images and I'm retrieving it form a MySQL Database however it is slow any way to increase the Image rendering?

any help would be great :)

My Code

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlst" runat="server" DataKeyField="ProductID"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3" >
        <HeaderTemplate>

        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnpopup" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "GetImage.aspx?id=" + Eval("ProductID") %>' Width="200px" Height="200px" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProductID") %>' CommandName="popup"   CausesValidation="false" BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderColor="WhiteSmoke" />


        </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:DataList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:smokeshopConnectionString %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:smokeshopConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT ProductID, Name, Description, ProductImage FROM products"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My Second page Called GetImage

```
string id = Request.QueryString["id"];

        MySqlDataReader r = db.getImage(id);

        while(r.Read())
        {
            byte[] imgData = (byte[])r["ProductImage"];
            Response.BinaryWrite(imgData);
            Response.Flush();
        }
```

Comment: you shouldn't save the image INTO the database. Save file path instead. Store them in web server as files.

Answer (score 2):

- Save the image on your web server and only save the file name in database. It will surely speed things up.
- The browser maintains only a limited no. of connections to given subdomain and all your images are returned from the same subdomain so that may also be a reason for slow rendering. Consider generating each image tag with with different sub domain (but same for given image) by hashing image id. This will make image download parallel.
  For example, static1.yourdomain.com/image1.jpg, static2.yourdomain.com/image2.jpg
- Since each subdomain adds a dns lookup overhead, be sure to not add too many sub domains.
- Do not resize images in html with height and width attribute but instead keep a 200x200 (in your case) image already saved and render that.
- Increase compression level of images on server (depending upon image quality requirement you may have)

Comment: Thank you I did that in the beginning however the problem was I would have to republish the web site every time I add a new item. However with image saved directly to the database I would only have to update the database.